# USB to LPT adapter?

Tags: usb, adapter, parallel-port, dongle

I'm bummed out, pretty much all of our computers here lack parallel ports.  I have an EETools ChipMax programming tool that has one of the old-school Centronics connectors on the back.  I figured that someone must make a USB to LPT adapter.  Sure enough, I found one from iogear, the GUC1284B that is a USB to Parallel **Printer** cable.  Note the boldface on the **Printer**.  It must connect to a printer -- it isn't some generic USB to parallel interface, unfortunately.

Does anyone here know of an adapter that works for parallel devices that **aren't** printers?  I'd hate to have to buy a USB version of the ChipMax when I don't need to use it very much.

Comment: this sounds like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/119209/will-parallel-port-dongle-work-on-usb-to-parallel-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the interface is only uni-directional, meaning it is meant to send information to the printer, but not get anything back.  If your device needs bi-directional communication, you may be out of luck.

Comment: good question... I'll need to research this, but I'm starting to think that I had better make sure I always have one PC with a parallel port, just in case.  :(

Comment: As long as you have a PC that will accept it, PCI parallel port controller cards are less than $20.

Comment: I'll have to look around for PCIe... thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the USB adaptor actually provides a full pinout for the printer port, and the GUC1284B expects nothing unusual, you could probably just buy, or buy parts and make if you can't find one pre-assembled, a female-IEEE1284-to->parallel cable. That might work.

In fact if you can find a IEEE1284 gender-changer you could probably use that with standard printer cable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you.  I need a USB to generic parallel interface.  The issue isn't centronics to DB25...